# Redirect urls in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a problem.
My app server is nginx, on which my blog was hosted.
when i visited my sitemap with this url:
http://www.ikbear.com/sitemap.xml, it works.But when i visited my sitemap with this url:
http://ikbear.com/sitemap.xml, it doesn't work. So i want to redirect http://ikbear.com/sitemap.xml to http://www.ikbear.com/sitemap.xml, would you tell me how can i do that in nginx? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I'm going to venture a guess that you'll have the same trouble redirecting that url as actually serving it.

First, here's the syntax for a basic redirect:

```
server {
    # ... 

    # redirect sitemap.xml to sitemap.xml.php
    rewrite ^(/sitemap.xml)$ /sitemap.xml.php;

    # ... 
}
```

What might work for you is getting both `www` and `not-www` serving correctly. A common strategy is to serve all `www` to `non-www`, or vice versa. Here's an example of that:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    # forward everything from www.domain.com to domain.com
    rewrite ^(.*) http://domain.com$1 permanent;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name  domain.com *.domain.com;

    location / {
            root   /var/www/domain/htdocs;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;

            # ... etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
I have resolved this problem thanks to this link:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-with-sitemap-1